# Evaluate CoreData entity type in predicate

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a block predicate that I carefully crafted only to discover you can't use them in Core Data.

```
NSPredicate *rootContactPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

        BOOL isPersonAndRoot = ([[[evaluatedObject entity] name] isEqualToString:@"Person"] && [[(Person*)evaluatedObject accounts] count] == 0);
        BOOL isAccountAndRoot = ([[[evaluatedObject entity] name] isEqualToString:@"Account"] && [(Account*)evaluatedObject root] == nil);

        return isPersonAndRoot || isAccountAndRoot;
    }];
```

So I need to convert this into a standard String format predicate, but I am unclear on how to check the entity type for the evaluated object. The `Person` and `Account` entities are subclasses of a `Contact` entity which is the type being evaluated in the fetch request. I'm hoping it will see the sub-types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that now you can now simply compare the entity in a predicate, supplying the managed objects entity as the value:

```
"entity = %@"
```

---

Previously:

You can't. The reason is that the predicate will need to be converted so that it can be run on the underlying data store (presumably SQLite). The SQLite database doesn't have any data on the type of the element, it only knows about the keys and values of the objects.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you'll either need to run a single fetch request against the keys known in the super entity. Or you'd need to have 2 fetch requests, separately executed and then combine the 2 result sets.

Comment: I was hoping that entity.name would resolve to something ... it didn't.

Comment: This is the difference between the data held in the model (compiled with the app) and the data held in the SQLite file...

Comment: mahal's suggestion below worked beautifully. As did the Swift version by Stuart Pattison. I used it to exclude particular sub-entities when fetching values from a parent abstract entity.

Answer (score 4):

Check the entity like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.entity = %@", Person.entity];
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.0 way of checking for entity type using the entity property of the NSManagedObject as per malhal's suggestion.

```
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Account", in: managedObjectContext)!
return NSPredicate(format: "entity = %@", entityDescription)
```

Comment: This worked! I used it to exclude particular sub-entities when fetching values from a parent abstract entity with the format "entity <> %@"

Comment: @aleksey can you provide that in code? It would be great to have a more sophisticated answer to help deconstruct what is going on.